# Changing CCK field values from view list

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-6, cck, taxonomy

I have a content type Task, where we create task for ourself or user and in that there is a drop down, which contains some taxonomy terms, which show the status of task.
Below this form I list the all the task for current user which shows some input values of content type task in some columns.
I want to show the status(CCK field) in a column as select box, which will show the current status of task and user can select some other status & submit it directly. So that user will not have to go to task node.

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Solved it by module - editablefield module :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Upload - editablefield module
2. Enable it
3. Go to the view (or create view)
4. Add CCK field under content
5. Select Editable Field under "Format"